# Resistor on data line between SK6812MINI-E and an MCU

Tags: microcontroller, led, resistors, ohms-law, rgb

Im getting pretty confused by the resistor that is supposed to be between the DIN of the first SK6812MINI-E and the pin of the MCU. The LEDS are being powered by a 5V 2A power supply (but should only draw 1.045A if my calculations) Now the datasheet says it should be 300-500 ohms, but Im not sure about the power rating. Some people say 10W, some say its not relevant and that I should pick whichever I want in the package I want. Im honestly not really sure.

Comment: It’s just a digital input, only a small amount of current needed. A 1/4 or 1/8W resistor should be fine. 10W is crazy.

Comment: It is a digital line and resistor only protect MCU output from sudden shortage. 330 Ohm is usual and size not matter.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. I wasnt sure since a lot of people say different things. Thanks